# Global dark mode settings for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

I have a flag in my `plist` where I'd like to change the style from light to dark mode. For example, for the `tabBar`, there is a dark style and same for `navigationBar`.

How can I set this globally instead of looking for all instances and setting them individually per `ViewController`. I tried to do something like this in the `AppDelegate`, but the properties I'm looking for aren't there:

```
UITableViewController.appearance()
UINavigationBar.appearance()
UIToolbar.appearance()
UITabBarController.appearance()
```

Is there a way to do this?